# How not to update showModalBottomSheet when I move?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using `showModalBottomSheet` and when I start moving it off the edge to close it the widget is updated, how can I make the widget not update when I move `showModalBottomSheet`?

```
 await showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(13),
          topRight: Radius.circular(13),
        ),
      ),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      useRootNavigator: true,
      builder: (context) {
```

Comment: did you try returning a const widget in builder ? builder: (_) => const YourStatefulClass());

Comment: yes, I tried return a const widget

Comment: But there is an animation controller in the modal it will rebuild/repaint whenever you drag. Are you using a StatefulWidget inside the modal?

Comment: I am using StatefullWidget but there is no animation controller